# CefSharp language settings

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

I have a problem to set up the Browser (CefSharp) language for my application.
So in my Initialization config I already configure it to set the Local Language to German:

```
Public Sub InitializeChromium()
    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    settings.Locale = "de-DE"
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(_cachePath) Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(_cachePath)
    settings.PersistSessionCookies = True
    settings.CachePath = _cachePath
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
    browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(address:=lblWEBSiteURL.Text)
    pnlBrowser.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End Sub
```

The strange thing is that when I am starting the application as my project directly in Visual Studio everything works fine. And the pages load with the German preference language. But when I install the same application on the same PC, the pages are loading in English language.
I have tried to set:

```
    settings.Locale = "de"
    settings.AcceptLanguageList = "de,de-DE"
```

and also inserted the Local de.pak (language pak) in my application but still when I install it, it is always on English.
Do you have any suggestions or tips?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29

Comment: Check the log file see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file sounds like you haven't correctly included the pak file.

Comment: That was the problem. Thx too both of you.
        `Private _LocalesDirPath As String = O.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Locales")`
        
`settings.LocalesDirPath = _LocalesDirPath`

`settings.Locale = "de.pak"`